# What is the meaning of "break 2"?

Tags: php, break, control-structure

I always used and seen examples with just "break". What is the meaning of this:

```
 <?php 
    while ($flavor = "chocolate") { 
      switch ($flavor) { 
        case "strawberry"; 
            echo "Strawberry is stock!"; 
            break 2;    // Exits the switch and the while 
        case "vanilla"; 
            echo "Vanilla is in stock!"; 
            break 2;   // Exits the switch and the while 
        case "chocolate"; 
            echo "Chocolate is in stock!"; 
            break 2;    // Exits the switch and the while 
        default;     
            echo "Sorry $flavor is not in stock"; 
            break 2;    // Exits the switch and the while 
      } 
    } 
    ?>
```

Are there more available options available with the 'break' statement?

Comment: Did you notice the comments in the code example you just gave? I think they do a fairly good job explaining it.

Comment: So what it would be in this example if we would have only 'break', not 'break 2'?

Comment: It would stay within the `while` loop. And given the condition, it would output *Chocolate is in stock!* forever :)

Comment: The break can be used for 2 things. 
1. To end the case statements in a switch and don't continue execution with the other. 2. To terminate a loop immediately. The optional parameter defines the level of the statement to be terminated. And it's default value is 1.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [PHP docs on `break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

As noted in the comments it breaks out of the *switch and while*.

The following example would break out of all `foreach` loops:

```
foreach (...) {
  foreach (..) {
    foreach (...) {
      if ($condition) {
        break 3;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So in this case, it breaks the switch and the while

Comment: Just beware that it should be like ***break <integer>;***  As of PHP 5.4.0 You may not pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; break $num;) as the numerical argument.