# A better way to exit nested for loops in C++?

Tags: c++

Here are the only two ways I know that roughly makes sense:

```
for (){
    for (){
        if (found the target) goto cont;
    }
}
cont:;
```

I've seen people strongly recommending against using `goto`, but I feel like this is a pretty proper way of using it.

```
bool exit=false;
for (){
    for (){
        if (found the target){
            exit=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (exit) break;
}
```

I write a bit more code this way.

What would you say to be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `goto` or `break`, put the loop or loops in a function or lambda, and use a `return`.

Comment: `[&]{ for(){ for(){ if (found the target) return; } } }();`

Comment: For breaking out of nested loops, using `goto` is considered appropriate. See [this top-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517746/12149471) for further information.

Comment: It's a sure sign that the inner loop should be in a separate function.

Comment: You can also use exceptions but beware of the cost of throwing them.

Comment: Perhaps, `std::find_if` can be of use here?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You shouldn't do that, exactly because of the cost. Also anybody who'll need to debug your program will hate you.

Comment: Sometimes I miss the `break(2);` from other languages.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I miss that too in C/C++. I didn't know that this exists in other languages. Which other languages have that? Could you please give an example?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel For a modern example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552721/what-is-the-meaning-of-break-2

Answer (score 3):

You can add a layer of abstraction.  If this is a loop that will be used in multiple places, then wrap it in a function like

```
auto do_stuff(params_t params)
{
    for (...){
        for (...){
            if (found_the_target) return something;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is a one off, then you can create a lambda on the fly like

```
auto thing_i_wanted_to_know = [&]{ for(...){ 
                                       for(...){ 
                                           if (found_the_target) return something; 
                                       }
                                   } 
                                 }();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your nested loops the following way

```
bool exit=false;
for ( ; !exit; ){
    for ( ; !exit; ){
        if (found the target){
            exit=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Usually the inner for loop can be rewritten either like while or do-while loop avoiding using the `break` statement that makes the code more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this to be a valid use of `goto`, but I myself use flags for this.

---

As an experiment, I've also ported Java's named loops to C++, using macros.

Usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) LOOP_NAME(foo)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (i == 5 && j == 5)
            break(foo);
    }
}
```

[Implementation](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/imp-re/blob/master/src/macros/named_loops.h):

```
#define LOOP_NAME(name) \
    /* The variable in the conditions prevents `BREAK/CONTINUE` from */\
    /* being used outside of the loop with the matching name. */\
    if ([[maybe_unused]] constexpr bool _namedloop_InvalidBreakOrContinue = false) \
    { \
        [[maybe_unused]] LOOP_NAME_impl_cat(_namedloop_break_,name): break; \
        [[maybe_unused]] LOOP_NAME_impl_cat(_namedloop_continue_,name): continue; \
    } \
    else

#define LOOP_NAME_impl_cat(x, y) LOOP_NAME_impl_cat_(x, y)
#define LOOP_NAME_impl_cat_(x, y) x##y

#define BREAK(name) goto LOOP_NAME_impl_cat(_namedloop_break_,name)
#define CONTINUE(name) goto LOOP_NAME_impl_cat(_namedloop_continue_,name)

#ifdef __clang__
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wkeyword-macro"
#endif
#define break(x) BREAK(x)
#define continue(x) CONTINUE(x)
#ifdef __clang__
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```